# How to exit a loop on exception, but not re-raise every Exception type?

Tags: python, exception

I have a loop that I want to terminate on `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
while True:
    try:
        do_stuff()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cleanup()
        break
    except Exception as e:
        cleanup()
        raise e
```

This works fine, but the dual `cleanup()` seems very unclean to me. I don't like duplicated code. I tried using a context manager instead, but that introduced a lot of unnecessary complexity and nearly doubled the file size.

Is there a cleaner way to express my intent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `finally` keyword is exactly what you are looking for. [The doc on errors and exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) explains its usage.

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not

---

If the cleanup is only supposed to occur when leaving the loop, I suggest swapping the loop and the try :

```
try:
    while True:
        do_stuff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    cleanup()
```

Comment: No, because the `finally` would run regardless of whether an exception occurred or not.

Comment: What about putting the while inside the try, so that the finally is only executed when you exit the loop (ie, only when there is an error) ?

Comment: Very nice. This looks like the cleanest solution to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `BaseException` to catch both

```
try:
   do_stuff():
except BaseException as e:
    cleanup()
    if isinstance(e, KeyboardInterruption):
        break
    raise e
```

Also, you can use only `raise` instead of `raise e`

Comment: For my particular needs, the `raise e` part would have to be in the `else` part. Still, perfect solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the `finally` clause:

```
while True:
  try:
    do_stuff()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
  finally:
    cleanup()
```

`cleanup()` will always be called, whether or not the exception is raised or caught.

Comment: No, because the `finally` would run regardless of whether an exception occurred or not. `cleanup()` should only be called when exiting the loop.